# How do I find the duration of a user in Karate-Gatling?

Tags: performance-testing, karate

I am using Karate-Gatling combo for perormance testing. In 0.9.6, the Gatling logs included a thread index, from which I could determine how long each user took to finish the scenario. The logs no longer contain this information in 1.0.1.

Is there a way to get the information about time it took to process a single user in 1.0.1? Or am I stuck with some sort of statistics of `Duration*ConcurrentUsers/TotalUsers`?

Answer (score 0):

This is news to me. There have been some code contributions and no one else has reported this. The Gatling version has also been upgraded, and perhaps it is no longer supported. The best thing is for you to help us understand what should be changed and do some investigation. We have a nice [developer guide](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide), so you should be able to easily build from source.

I suspect it is this commit: https://github.com/intuit/karate/pull/1335/files

If if we don't get help, it is unlikely we resolve this as no one else has reported this.